# One liner for True or False for loop in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, one-liner

Almost every time I solve an exercise of Codewars and glance at others solutions I see that some guys do my 15 lines code in 2 or 3 lines. So, I have started to learn lists and sets comprehensions and would try other tricks. For now my question is about this code:

```
    for i in range (0, 3):
        if not text [i].isdecimal ():
            return False
```

Is it possible to write it in one line?

Comment: yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @buran I have tried variations of 
       `[text[i].isdecimal () for i in range (0, 3)]`
       `[True for i in text[i].isdecimal () for i in range (0, 3) else False]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `all`:

```
return all(text[i].isdecimal() for i in range(0,3))
```

`all` iterates through your list/generator/tuple/etc. and evaluates whether each item is true or false. It bails and returns `False` the first time it evaluates a `False`. `any` is similar, except it will look through everything for at least one truthy evaluation.

(I am assuming your original code is correct, and you're only interested in the first three elements of `text`, and that you're looking to return that value from whatever function you're in.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a more complex loop like this:

````
 for i in range(10):
    if i<5:
        j = i**2
    else:
        j = 0    
    print(j) ```
````

You can compress this into one line. Check out the following code snippet:

`for i in range(10): print(i**2 if i<5 else 0)`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong in the comments here, not sure how to give an exact answer to that, but this should hopefully help. :)

Comment: You can... but you can't do something like `x = for i in range(10): i**2 if i<5 else 0`. In the OP he's looking for some value he can consume somewhere else.